# Postcss extend along with css modules

Tags: webpack, postcss, css-modules

I have a following webpack configuration:

```
test: /.css$/,
use: extractAppStyles.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [{
        loader: 'css-loader',
        query: {
            modules: true,
            importLoaders: 1,
            sourceMaps: false
        }
    }, {
        loader: 'postcss-loader'
    }]
})
```

and `postcss.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('precss'),
        require("postcss-extend")
    ]
};
```

I want to use postcss-extend plugin in local css modules so that I can extend some globally defined selectors inside local modules, as such:

```
.test {
   @extend :global(.some-class);
}
```

where `.test`is local and `.some-class` is global. With the current setup, one can only extend locally defined selectors and globals seem to be undefined:

> ':global(.some-class)', has not been defined, so it cannot be
>   extended

The order of loaders seem to be the issue, I think modules are not resolved when processed by `postcss-extend` plugin. I tried to use `postcss-modules` plugin before `postcss-extend` but that did not work as expected.

Has anyone come up with idea how to combine using the two such that it is possible to locally extend globally defined selectors?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @robbertwbradford sorry, nope I didnt

Comment: Ok, thanks. I ended up being able to use https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#composition and https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#dependencies for my use case.